# Adobe XD HTML file export view size is way too big for the browser. How can I make it smaller?

Tags: html, adobe

I have a plugin in Adobe XD that allows for an HTML export. Once I open this file to view the outcome in my browser, the page is way too big for viewing which is making me zoom out to view the entire page. How can I fit this page into the browser for a proper view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never came accross this kind of error. I am new to XD so I mostly follow the tutorial which they have on their support forum.
Maybe this can help. Have a look.
[responsive resize](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/xd/help/using-responsive-resize.html)